# The average number of pending transactions within the pending pool

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, txpool

Is it possible to know the average number of pending transactions for a larger period of time? For this chart (https://etherscan.io/chart/pendingtx), I can only figure the most recent 5 days. I would like to make an estimation about the average pending transactions, so it would be great if I can get the data within a larger period of time.

While it is feasible to use `web3` API to get the real-time pending transactions, I am wondering whether it is also feasible to collect the historical data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Dapp or a wallet you can leverage the [Blocknative](https://www.blocknative.com/) API for Blockchain transaction notifications. For every single transaction on your Dapp it logs the pending transaction and you can store those in a database to keep track of changing transaction parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect real time txpool data using `web3.txpool.pending`. You can process and save the data to recreate an etherscan-like chart you described in the question.

It is impossible to collect the historical data from a node (if someone has saved it elsewhere and is offering it, you can get it this way). This is because these transactions are either included in a block or discarded completely. It is obvious that transactions included in a block *were* in the txpool, so I assume that information is not relevant to you. The transactions that are never included are not saved on the node layer, so you cannot collect historical data of transactions that have been dropped.